# Sharing localStorage data between different domains using iframe not working

Tags: javascript, local-storage, same-origin-policy, session-storage, postmessage

Im trying to follow this article that teaches us how to share localstorage data between domains if you have an iframe embedded.

https://www.internetkatta.com/share-cookies-or-local-storage-data-between-cross-domain

So to try it out, I created two separate projects with its own html files and index files respectively. I then launched both html files in the server using VS Code's live server. I was trying to get `http://127.0.0.1:5500/getlocalstorage.html` to pass in the user login data to `http://127.0.0.1:5501/getlocalstorage.html`, however, it returns no data in the localstorage tab and just shows as:

[image]

Is there anything I am doing wrong here? I am trying to pass in the dummy login info from localhost:5500 to localhost:5501. Please see my code below:

Localhost 5500's index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
      function postCrossDomainMessage(msg) {
        var win = document.getElementById("ifr").contentWindow;
        win.postMessage(msg, "http://127.0.0.1:5500/");
      }
      var postMsg = { login: "user" }; // this is just example
      postCrossDomainMessage(postMsg);
    </script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe
      style="display: none"
      src="http://127.0.0.1:5501/getlocalstorage.html"
      id="ifr"
    ></iframe>
    <h1>http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Localhost 5501's html file(getlocalstorage.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
      var PERMITTED_DOMAIN = "http://127.0.0.1:5500";
      /**
       * Receiving message from other domain
       */
      window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
        if (event.origin === PERMITTED_DOMAIN) {
          //var msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
          // var msgKey = Object.keys(msg)[0];
          if (event.data) {
            localStorage.setItem("localstorage", event.data);
          } else {
            localStorage.removeItem("localstorage");
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>http://127.0.0.1:5501/getlocalstorage.html</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

New Error that is being shown in console

localhost 5500 console error

Do you see anything that I might have done wrong here? Thanks!

This is in localhost 5500 tab:
[image]

And in localhost 5501 localstorage tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `script` tag is before the `iframe` tag. It is also executed before the `iframe` is created. Hence, searching for `ifr` returns `null` and `null` does not have a `contentWindow`, which throws an error. You will need to postpone the JS execution after the page load, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
      function postCrossDomainMessage(msg) {
        var win = document.getElementById("ifr").contentWindow;
        win.postMessage(msg, "http://127.0.0.1:5500/");
      }
      function load() {
          var postMsg = { login: "user" }; // this is just example
          postCrossDomainMessage(postMsg);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="load()">
    <iframe
      style="display: none"
      src="http://127.0.0.1:5501/getlocalstorage.html"
      id="ifr"
    ></iframe>
    <h1>http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that the `load` function is not executed in the `script` tag, only defined. It is the `onload` event defined in `body` that triggers it.

EDIT

The line of `localStorage.setItem("localstorage", event.data);` stores an item into `localStorage` with the key of `'localStorage'` and the value of `[Object object]`, because into localStorage you will store strings. So, you will need to stringify the object that you have. So, you will need to do something like

`localStorage.setItem("localstorage", JSON.stringify(event.data));`

And you can read from it via

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localStorage"))`

Example

[image]

Comment: Hey, appreciate the help. PERMITTED_DOMAIN is a variable holding http://127.0.0.1:5500

Comment: @KennyQuach oh, right. Sorry for missing that. Is the event executed at all? Can you put a `console.log(event.origin)` as the first operation? If so, what's the result?

Comment: no problem! I have updated my post to show what I get when I console log it @Lajos

Comment: Okay, I see the error message is complaining that the script is executed before the `iframe` is created. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @KennyQuach edited my answer. My current answer surely fixes an error that you have. I cannot guarantee that this is the only error, but I can guarantee that this is surely an error. Let me know if your test works now and if not, then what the new error is.

Comment: Hey Lajos, thanks again. So in the localhost 5500 tab, im getting an error:
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://127.0.0.1:5500') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://127.0.0.1:5501').

And in the localhost:5501 tab, im getting something in the localstorage which is:
[object Object]

I will update my post to show what I mean

Comment: @KennyQuach that's good news! This means that so far the app crashed for not finding the iframe. Now the message is attempted to be sent but you get a CORS error.

Comment: I have updated the code, and im glad that its getting closer to the solution! @Lajos

Comment: @KennyQuach looking into this CORS problem.

Comment: @KennyQuach a solution can be found at https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-windowpostmessage-make-cross-origin-http-requests-elnur-babayev/

Comment: @KennyQuach it is also possible that you need CORS headers at the site that you load at the iframe, it is possible that the browser throws the error because the target site did not specify that it welcomes messages from other origins. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thanks for your help again. Yea, I am still figuring it out. Ill keep looking but I really appreciate you taking the time to help @Lajos

Comment: Actually the error went away and I guess right now I am just figuring out the issue with the localstorage object showing as [object Object]

Comment: @KennyQuach I know the solution for that. Bear with me, I will post a message here soon.

Comment: @KennyQuach edited my answer with details that will hopefully help in fixing the current issue.

Comment: @KennyQuach I'm wrapping up for today, tomorrow I will look into your possible response to my latest edit.

Comment: Ok! Have a good night and thank you!